# Fibonacci sequence problem

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

**Question:**

Show that if $ $ $ k |n \implies F_k |F_n$

$ $

**Comments:**

I ran into this problem the other day and have not figured it out yet. I think it has something to do with the order of the period of the Fibonacci sequence modulo $m$, for some $ m \in \Bbb{N}$